# onsen-ui postclose not triggered with swiping

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

HTML:

```
 <ons-sliding-menu
                      main-page="page1.html"
                      menu-page="sidemenu.html"
                      side="left"
                      max-slide-distance="250px"
                      var="sidemenu"
                      type="reveal"
                      swipe-target-width="40px">
    </ons-sliding-menu>
```

JS:

```
sidemenu.on('postclose', function() {
            $scope.show_y = false;
            $scope.show_x = true;
        });
```

the `postclose` function is not triggered when user swipes menu closed,

clicks work fine though....

advise please?

UPDATE ---

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope) { return $scope.sidemenu.isMenuOpened(); }, 
                  function() {
                    alert('hi');
                  });
```

not even `isMenuOpened()` is fired with swipe events on the sidemenu.

I started a new project with a bare bones side-menu and angular directive, no change, no errors logged.

Comment: preopen does not fire with swipe either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `$evalAsync` on variable changes to be digested by angular

```
sidemenu.on('preopen', function() {
            $scope.$evalAsync( function() {
                $scope.sm_main_cover = true;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ons-sliding-menu` element object inside the javascript is `$scope.sidemenu` and not `sidemenu`, try modifying it and see if it works.

If it still doesn't work probably is because:

- the controller is not declared correctly inside the HTML (for example: doesn't cover the portion of code where the sliding menu in declared)
- the code that creates the `ons-sliding-menu`listener is never executed, so the listener doesn't exist

EDIT

This is a example that I have implemented in one of my apps

```js
app.controller('SlidingMenuController', function($scope){
      
    $scope.checkSlidingMenuStatus = function(){
          
        $scope.slidingMenu.on('postclose', function(){
            $scope.slidingMenu.setSwipeable(false);
        });
        $scope.slidingMenu.on('postopen', function(){
            $scope.slidingMenu.setSwipeable(true);
        });
    };
      
    $scope.checkSlidingMenuStatus();
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i have a single global controller on the template - its a single page app in dev - so only one directive... click events register no problem - so the angular is properly watching and changing the variable, the postopen function is specific to ONSEN-UI, and that is not listening to the sidemenu postopen event

Comment: Did you check that the code creating the listener is executed and there's no js errors?

Comment: yes - there are no errors @AndreasArgelius, can you reproduce the error on your end? it seems non of the helper functions fire when swiping sidemenu, clicks register fine and helper functions work when CLICKED.... soooooo, onsen-ui + swipe not listening?